# How to trigger data display without reloading using handlebar and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, express, handlebars.js

So I have a simple login page like this:

```
    <form class="form-container" method="post" action="/login">

      <div class="container">
        <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

        <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

        <div id="alertContainer" class="alert-container">{{data}}</div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
```

note that the `alertContainer` is a div reserved to display any errors. For example, if the username is not found, I want to display `"Username not found"` here, Hence the `handlebars` syntax `{{data}}`

My backend `POST` request using express looks like this:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    var user = //find user in database;

    if(!user) {
        var data = "Username not found";
        // somehow get to page to display data
    }

    // do other things
});
```

The problem is I only know how to re-render the page to pass in data. But I only want a simple error string to be displayed `alertContainer` without refreshing the whole page. I can, of course, add some `Ajax` script to the bottom of the `html` page but I'm not sure how to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

try this: 

 
if (!user) { 
       document.getElementById("alertContainer").innerHTML = "Username not found";

    }

Comment: I can't do that, `user` is being checked on the server side. `document` wouldn't be defined.